# Calling templates using razor multiline calls

Tags: asp.net-mvc, templates, razor, render

I'm starting in ASP.NET MVC/razor and I need to implement a `div` that will have a variable number of different buttons.

I heard something about implementing templates and calling them this way, in a razor view:

```
@Project.UI.ActionButtonsPanel()
    .AddButton(ActionButtons.Submit)
    .AddButton(ActionButtons.Cancel, ActionButtons.Reset)
    .AddButton(new CustomActionButton(0, "Execute", ActionButtonGroup.Primary, "url"))
    .AddButton(new CustomActionButton("Accept", ActionButtonGroup.Primary, "url"))
    .HtmlAttribute(new { id=""})
    .Render();
```

But, after a research I was not able to find anything talking about this.

Is this implementation possible? If so, how can I do this?

Comment: Sounds like you want to create a `Fluent` interface. This uses chained methods to express a problem in a meaningful way. It can be a lot more work, compared to traditional coding, so make sure the project warrants the investment.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap the entire expression in parentheses.

Comment: Ok, but, how do I implement the template?

Comment: @user3280293: Are you asking how to write the functions or how to call them in Razor syntax?